# Coordinating data from two events to an UI thread in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, serial-port

I am writing C# WPF code to spy on a serial port (debugging tool). I am creating two virtual ports connected as null modem with com0com (app) and using my code to read off one port and immediately send out the other port, and vice versa:

```
HOST <--> Virtual COM <--> C# spy app <--> Real COM <--> TARGET
```

For this, I have created one class to manage a SerialPort object that creates an DataReceived event. In this implementation, I would have two instances of this class, one to manage HOST communication and the other for the target. The UI will only parse and display data from these two classes.

The problem: serial ports run on different threads than UI... and I have two of them trying to update the same UI.

My approach to this is to create a public `List<T>` where T could be a `struct { byte[] data; Direction direction}` to which each event handler would append its data, while the UI could parse this data. Event handlers would do List.Add(), while UI would do List.RemoveAt(0) while data exists. Data speed: 19200bps (1 byte every 0.5ms).

Questions: 
Can event handlers from two different serial ports interrupt each other and corrupt List data?
Would using a List object affect performance? Should I try with an array of struct and just keep track of indices?

Or should I do something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can event handlers from two different serial ports interrupt each other and corrupt List data?

Absolutely, the DataReceived event is raised on a threadpool thread.  You've got a three-ring circus going on here, two threads that can receive something at the same time, an UI thread that's reading the received data at the same time.  Locking is required to protect the List<>.

Comment: Locking would be a problem. Serial ports are running on critical timing, meaning that data being transmitted cannot be interrupted, i.e. as soon as data comes, it needs to be pushed the other way. I can have each serial port object keep a circular buffer and have the UI try to catch up. There would be no locking needed, but I would lose the ability to tell which data came first from each of the serial ports...

Comment: ... but on the other hand, I created a quick test app with two serial ports: Serial1 and Serial2, where each had a DataReceived event and on each DataReceived, I would immediately send data out the other port. E.g. Serial1_DataReceived { while(Serial1.HasDataInBuffer) Serial2.Send(Serial1.Buffer); } If the ports run on different threads, why does this compile and work?

Comment: No, serial port data is buffered by the driver.  19200 baud is glacially slow for modern machines.  You can increase the receive buffer size if that makes you comfortable, ReadBufferSize property.  Besides, you only lock for a very short time, just the queue's add and remove methods which execute in a handful of nanoseconds.  Calling the Send() method is thread-safe, the driver serializes the writes.

Comment: Thanks, answered all my concerns!